# rxswift URLSession getting string response

Tags: ios, swift

Here i can only get `2021-01-30 00:24:02.422625+0300 HB_iTunesDemo[66115:3533298] 4676 bytes` on the debug log. I need to print full string

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(query)&limit=\(size)&media=\(mediatype)")!)
        return URLSession.shared.rx.data(request: request)
            .map { data -> String in
                NSLog(data.description)
                return data.description
            }
```

Comment: `NSLog(data.description)` ? `data` That's a `(NS)Data` object. Maybe with `String(data: data, encoding: utf8)`? But maybe it's JSON, so a JSON parsing might be better (Codable ? JSONSerialization ?)

Comment: its full string https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Java&limit=2&media=ebook

Comment: prints like this Success (1ms): Status 200
2021-01-30 00:32:22.624267+0300 HB_iTunesDemo[66235:3541851] p±áˇ

Comment: this response cant parse into decodable json because it has 3 \n at the start